# How to get the IP address of a LAN computer by name in Android

Tags: android

I have a computer in the LAN and I'd like to get its IP address by its name from a phone. I learned that using InetAddress would give me the IP.

If I use a browser, I can see the computer.

I used the following code:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("computer1");
if(address!=null)
  Log.w("DEBUG",address.getHostAddress().toString());
else
  Log.w("DEBUG","No ip found");
```

All I get is an exception:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:325)
        at com.example.Data.BGTask.AdatSzinkronizalas(DataTask.java:470)
        at com.example.Data.BGTask.doInBackground(DataTask.java:237)
        at com.example.Data.BGTask.doInBackground(DataTask.java:51)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

What else should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, I have to use a full domain name of the computer to get its IP address. So instead of

> computer1

I had to use

> computer1.mydomain.local

With this, Android was able to get the IP address. I wonder if the full name is mandatory only in AD environments or any single PC should use some sort of full name.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are using is fine. It appears that "computer1" doesn't resolve when the app does a lookup. Make sure that the device's DNS server is able to resolve the hostname you're trying to reference.

Comment: What do you mean by the device's DNS server? The phone is a Galaxy Young (Android 2.3), it uses the standard network options. It is on the same network as the LAN computer.

Comment: Network interfaces (such as wifi/ethernet/etc.) usually have a domain name server configured. You're probably connecting via DHCP and your router would assign an address for the name server, with it most likely pointing to an ip setup on the router. If you are able to, try looking up "computer1" from another machine connected to your network in the same why by trying this command from that computer: `nslookup computer1`.

Comment: Strange. I get this message: 
C:\Users\user>nslookup computer1
Host:  UnKnown
Address:  10.111.111.2

*** UnKnown - computer1 cannot be found: Non-existent domain

Comment: Ok, then 10.111.111.2 is the dns server ip and it doesn't know about "computer1" which is exactly why you're getting a `UnknownHostException` thrown. If it was configured on the dns server (which may not be possible on your router), it should return what you expected in the first place.

Comment: But if the DNS server doesn't know it, how can I ping it by name?

Comment: That's a good question. It would have to resolve the hostname in order to ping its ip address.